# Simple jQuery code about using variables

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".role").change(function(){
            var userId=$(this).attr('name');
            return $("form[id=userId]").submit(); 
        });
    })
```

In the above code, I already checked that `'userId'` gets an appropriate value through printing its value through `'alert'`. Also, I already checked that `$("form[id='1']").submit();` is okay.

However, the above code doesn't work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string should be concatenated

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".role").change(function(){
        var userId=$(this).attr('name');
        return $("form[id=" + userId + "]").submit(); 
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".role").change(function(){
            var userId=this.name;
            return $("form[id='"+userId+"']").submit(); 
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

User id is a varaible ... Try the below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){         
$(".role").change(function(){             
var userId=$(this).attr('name'); 
        return $("form[id=" +userId+ "]").submit();
      });    
 })
```